# How can I make org-protocol work on Openbox?

Tags: firefox, emacs, org-mode

I tried [the instructions](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html)  - I am using Firefox on [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) ([Openbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox)). But I get the error

> "Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (org-protocol) isn't associated with any program".

How should I fix this?

Comment: I had a similar problem before. See this thread, the solution described there worked for me: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-05/msg00289.html

Comment: I tried the above, but when I got an error "The databases in [.local/share/applications/] could not be updated.", and I am still unable to open org-protocol link or just org-protocol:// in the location bar.

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to configure Archlinux+AwesomeWM+Firefox to work, even following the procedure didn't seem to want to associate the protocol (even after manually adding it in about:config). However as a work-around/alternative I was able to get it working in Opera following the instructions. Would be nice to have a clearer description of how to make it work if you're not using gnome/gconf however.

Comment: use `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/` instead.

Answer (score 22):

The following steps for setting up [org-protocol](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html) work with [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) and presumably later versions.  Org-mode is assumed to have already been set-up (and installed using `apt-get install org-mode` or via the [ELPA repository](https://elpa.gnu.org/)).

## Set-up

1. Add .desktop file

---

Create and save a file called `org-protocol.desktop` to ~/.local/share/applications containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=org-protocol
Exec=emacsclient %u
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=System;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/org-protocol;
```

Then run:

```
$ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
```

This step makes Firefox aware that "org-protocol" is a valid scheme-handler or protocol (by updating `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`), and causes Firefox to prompt for a program to use when opening these kinds of links.

2. Add config settings to ~/.emacs.d/init.el (or ~/.emacs) file

---

Have the following settings in your Emacs configuration file:

```
(server-start)
(require 'org-protocol)
```

Also add some template definitions to the configuration file, for example:

```
(setq org-protocol-default-template-key "l")
(setq org-capture-templates
 '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "/path/to/notes.org" "Tasks")
        "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")
   ("l" "Link" entry (file+olp "/path/to/notes.org" "Web Links")
        "* %a\n %?\n %i")
   ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "/path/to/journal.org")
        "* %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

Now run Emacs.

3. Create your `notes.org` file

---

Assuming you use the capture templates defined in step 2, you will need to prepare a `notes.org` file at the location you specified in step 2.  You **must** create this file -- if it is not created along with the headlines specified in step 2, org-mode will just give a warning when you try to capture web-pages.  So, given the capture templates from step 2, `notes.org` should contain the following:

```
* Tasks
* Web Links
```

4. Add bookmarklet(s) to Firefox

---

Save bookmark to toolbar containing something like the following as the location:

```
javascript:location.href='org-protocol://capture?template=l&url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'&body='+encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())
```

If you are using an older version of org-mode, you may need to use the following instead:

```
javascript:location.href='org-protocol://capture://l/'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())
```

Notice the 'l' (lowercase L) in the above URL -- this is what chooses the capture template (automatically) -- it is the key one would normally have to press when capturing with org-mode via C-c c.

When you click on this bookmarklet, Firefox will ask what program to use to handle the "org-protocol" protocol.  You can simply choose the default program that appears ("org-protocol").

## Using it

(Optionally) select some text on a webpage you're viewing in Firefox. When you click on the bookmarklet, the link and selected text will be placed in the Emacs capture buffer. Go to Emacs, modify the capture buffer as desired, and press `C-c C-c` to save it.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, I also had to set `xdg-open` as the application to be executed by Firefox when Firefox presents its application chooser dialog.

Comment: I think in your bookmark, `capture://l/'+` should be `capture://'+`.

Comment: @BradyTrainor No, the `l` chooses the capture template.

Answer (score 12):

## Add protocol handler

Create file `~/.local/share/applications/org-protocol.desktop` containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=org-protocol
Exec=emacsclient %u
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=System;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/org-protocol;
```

**Note:** Each line's key must be capitalized exactly as displayed, or it will be an invalid `.desktop` file.

Then update `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` by running:

- On GNOME:

  ```
  update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
  ```
- On KDE:

  ```
  kbuildsycoca4
  ```

## Configure Emacs

### Init file

Add to your Emacs init file:

```
(server-start)
(require 'org-protocol)
```

### Capture template

You'll probably want to add a capture template something like this:

```
("w" "Web site"
 entry
 (file+olp "/path/to/inbox.org" "Web")
 "* %c :website:\n%U %?%:initial")
```

**Note:** Using `%:initial` instead of `%i` seems to handle multi-line content better.

This will result in a capture like this:

```
\* [[http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html][org-protocol.el – Intercept calls from emacsclient to trigger custom actions]] :website:
[2015-09-29 Tue 11:09] About org-protocol.el

org-protocol.el is based on code and ideas from org-annotation-helper.el and org-browser-url.el.
```

## Configure Firefox

### Expose protocol-handler

On some versions of Firefox, it may be necessary to add this setting.  You may skip this step and come back to it if you get an error saying that Firefox doesn't know how to handle `org-protocol` links.

Open `about:config` and create a new `boolean` value named `network.protocol-handler.expose.org-protocol` and set it to `true`.

**Note:** If you do skip this step, and you do encounter the error, Firefox may replace all open tabs in the window with the error message, making it difficult or impossible to recover those tabs.  It's best to use a new window with a throwaway tab to test this setup until you know it's working.

### Make bookmarklet

Make a bookmarklet with the location:

```
javascript:location.href='org-protocol://capture://w/'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())
```

**Note:** The `w` in the URL chooses the corresponding capture template.  You can leave it out if you want to be prompted for the template.

When you click on this bookmarklet for the first time, Firefox will ask what program to use to handle the `org-protocol` protocol.  If you are using [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), you must add the `/usr/bin/emacsclient` program, and choose it. With [Ubuntu 12.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal) or later, you can simply choose the default program that appears (`org-protocol`).

You can select text in the page when you capture and it will be copied into the template, or you can just capture the page title and URL.

### Tridactyl

If you're using [Tridactyl](https://github.com/tridactyl/tridactyl), you can map key sequences something like this:

```
bind cc js location.href='org-protocol://capture://w/'+encodeURIComponent(content.location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(content.document.title)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(content.document.getSelection())
```

You might also want to add one for the `store-link` sub-protocol, like:

```
bind cl js location.href='org-protocol://store-link://'+encodeURIComponent(content.location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(content.document.title)
```

## Capture script

You may want to use this script to capture input from a terminal, either as an argument or piped in:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $@ ]]
then
    data="$@"
else
    data=$(cat)
fi

if [[ -z $data ]]
then
    exit 1
fi

encoded=$(python -c "import sys, urllib; print urllib.quote(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]), safe='')" "${data[@]}")

# "link" and "title" are not used, but seem to be necessary to get
# $encoded to be captured
emacsclient "org-protocol://capture://link/title/$encoded"
```

Then you can capture input from the shell like this:

```
tail /var/log/syslog | org-capture

org-capture "I can capture from a terminal!"
```

*These instructions are more up-to-date than the ones in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464951/how-can-i-make-org-protocol-work-on-openbox/12751732#12751732).*

Comment: Hi,
I had org-protocol working from Firefox. However, I had to create another Firefox profile and I am unable to make it work again.
Every time I try to capture something,  Firefox says it doesn't know how to handle org-protocol links.
I've already exposed org-protocol by acessing "about:config" but the problem remains. I think it is something on Firefox and not on emacs or OS, since when I use the old Firefox profile, org-capture works.
Is there something else to configure in Firefox, besides exposing org-protocol in about:config?

Thanks,

Renato.

Comment: Hi Renato, I'm afraid I don't have any idea why it wouldn't work on a new profile.  It's possible that Mozilla's broken something in Firefox that's related to this; if so, good luck figuring that out.  The only thing I can suggest is to try all the steps again on another new profile, to make sure you didn't make any little mistakes or typos.  You might also try it on another system, another OS, another Firefox version, another user account, etc; maybe if you can find another combination that works, it will help you narrow it down.  Please let us know if you find a solution.

Comment: Hi, I've found a solution. I've acessed Firefox about:config and created a boolean value named network.protocol-handler.expose.org-protocol set to false. For Firefox to recognize the org-protocol handler, I had to create a local HTML file with a link to an org-protocol resource. After restarting Firefox, opening this file and clicking on the link, Firefox opened a window asking what to do (this window was not showed by simply typing the org-protocol address in the address bar). In this window, I could select the previously created org-protocol desktop entry. Thanks!

Comment: The Tridactyl tip and shell-script were particularly useful, thanks!