# getting org-protocol to work on Firefox Quantum -- `No server buffers remain to edit` error

Tags: firefox, emacs, org-mode

So I am trying to get `org-protocol` to work for the first time on Firefox Quantum. I worked through a variety of blog posts and the documentation, but still cannot get past this particular error

```
Greedy org-protocol handler.  Killing client. 
No server buffers remain to edit.
```

So I am using emacs 25.3 on Ubuntu Linux x64 16.04, and the newly released Firefox Quantum.

I tried to do this in two ways.

1. The traditional approach of setting up `org-protocol` through creating a desktop entry and then setting up bookmarklets in Firefox.
2. Using the `org-capture` add-on in Firefox.

Both are giving me the same error.

For approach 1, I followed the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html#sec-6-1) as well as a very helpful stackexchange post:

[How to make org-protocol work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464951/how-to-make-org-protocol-work)

There was also this useful blog [post](http://www.mediaonfire.com/blog/2017_07_21_org_protocol_firefox.html).

Here is what I did:

A. I created a desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=org-protocol
Exec=emacsclient -n %u
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=System;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/org-protocol;
```

B. added config to `.spacemacs` file.

I added the lines:

```
(server-start)
(require 'org-protocol)
```

Then I setup up the capture template in my `.spacemacs` file:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote 
              ("p" "org-protocol" entry (file+headline "~/Dropbox/config/org/refile/refile.org")
                "* %^{Title}\nSource: %u, %c\n #+BEGIN_QUOTE\n%:initial\n#+END_QUOTE\n\n\n%?")
              ("l" "org-protocol link" entry (file "~/Dropbox/config/org/refile/refile.org")
                "* %? [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured On: %U")
... Additional templates.
))
```

C. Then I created the bookmarklets with the locations:

```
javascript:location.href='org-protocol://store-link://l/'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)

javascript:location.href='org-protocol://capture://l/'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())
```

After all of this, I still get the error message referenced above.

Second, I tried the `org-capture` add-on in Firefox. But it did not work either.

Not sure what the cause of the error is. Any help is appreciated.

In other reading people get this `Greedy` error when there are problems in the `org-capture` template, but I did not find any errors.

Comment: I have exactly followed the same steps from what I've seen in online resources. I figured out that the problem is Pandoc. I am a naive user of Linux, I simply run pandoc once in the terminal and then open emacs, then everything is fine. It seems the original problem is that pandoc is not getting invoked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble in the past too.

Now the solution I use is this [firefox add-on](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension) -> You can install it directly from Firefox. That's really easy and in my case, it worked out of the box (Debian distro, Firefox 52.5.0). I do not know if it is available for Firefox Quantum though.

[org-protocol](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html) is configured as usual. In my case:

```
cat > "${HOME}/.local/share/applications/org-protocol.desktop" << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=org-protocol
Exec=emacsclient %u
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=System;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/org-protocol;
EOF
```

then

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
```

In your Emacs `init.el` file:

```
(server-start)
(require 'org-protocol)

(setq org-capture-templates `(
    ("p" "Protocol" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "notes.org") "Inbox")
        "* %^{Title}\nSource: %u, %c\n #+BEGIN_QUOTE\n%i\n#+END_QUOTE\n\n\n%?")
    ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "notes.org") "Inbox")
        "* %? [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured On: %U")
))
```

That's all. Under my config it works, I hope this is the same for yours.

---

**Extra:** some time ago, I have suggested a small template improvement to handle ArXiv.org titles, the details are here: https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension/issues/37

Comment: thanks for the note. Yeah, I tried the org-capture-extension in Firefox as well, but I still keep getting the error `No server buffers remain to edit`. I will post to the sprig repo under and issue and see if he has any suggestions. Yeah, I would love to see a template for Arxiv files too. Great.

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback. I have no idea concerning this error, sorry. Keep us informed if you solve the problem.

Comment: Have you seen this post https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension/issues/1 ? ->

Comment: yep I saw that post. I think in that case the cause was that the template shortcut was a mismatch to the extension settings. So the user was using "w" instead of "p." However in my case I am using the correct "p" extension. I even copied and pasted the capture template you specified in your post, but still running into this issue. Same problem occurs in Google Chrome too. So somewhere I have a config issue but not sure where.

Comment: ok, sad to hear. I hope you will manage to fix it, I have no other idea for the moment.

Comment: I figured it out @Picaud. It was not very obvious, but there was a change to the `use-package` package that was interferring with the operation of the `org-capture` function. So the problem was not related to the extension, but the problem presented itself when using the extension. So anyway, I wrote up the solution above. Thanks for your suggestions and tips.

Comment: @krishnab thanks for the feedback and clarification. I m not using use-package, but that is a good thing to have fixed the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was a tricky solution. The problem was caused by some recent changes in the `use-package` emacs package. The issue is documented on github.

https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/557

Let me tell you how I found the issue in case you get other people registering similar issues.

I set up the org-capture-extension as you recommended in the README, however I keep getting the following error (posted below) in emacs Messages buffer. I am using Emacs 25.3 on Ubuntu 16.04x64 with the new Firefox Quantum browser as well as Chrome.

So I tried to manually pass a link through the emacsclient with the following command

```
emacsclient -n "org-protocol:///capture?url=http%3a%2f%2fduckduckgo%2ecom&title=DuckDuckGo"
```

But I kept getting this strange response in the Messages buffer where there was a cycling behavior between warning349 and warning 931.

```
condition-case: Symbol’s value as variable is void: use-package--warning349
condition-case: Symbol’s value as variable is void: use-package--warning931
condition-case: Symbol’s value as variable is void: use-package--warning349
condition-case: Symbol’s value as variable is void: use-package--warning931
condition-case: Symbol’s value as variable is void: use-package--warning349
```

The solution is documented in the github issue, but I don't think that users should manually implement the fix. Instead I think that the author will make the change and merge it into master--at which time users can redownload and install the `use-package` package.